# How to convert a OutputStream object to a file object?

Tags: java, file, file-io, fileoutputstream

I need to convert an image file(large size to small size). So, I am decoding image file to bitmap image and then I compressed bitmap image. I need to save this bitmap into File object again. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Please provide us some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you.

Comment: What does your image file look like? What are you currently stumbling with? Can you post your current code?. There is no way to answer this without more details -- and also, showing that you have made an effort to solve it goes a long way towards getting others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

first covert your bitmap to byte[] object by

```
    Bitmap bmp; //your bitmap object
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Then create a FileOutputStream Object and write the byte[] to the fileoutputstream

```
    File yourOutputFile = new File("/the/path/to/your/file")
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(yourOutputFile);
    fos.write(byteArray);
    fos.close();

    return yourOutputFile;//this will be your output
```

Comment: Can you help that, I need the output as a File object.